# Want to match an expression starting with @ and has 1-3 digits and 1-10 words in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am using the following regex for matching an expression starting with @ and has 1-3 digits and 1-10 words in PHP `\W\d{1,3}\w{1,10}`.

Example of the matched string should be `@123ABcdEFCFhG` or `@12Abc`

But PHP preg_match returns true for `@12345ABCSCCVSVCVSCHSCHSCHSHC` any length of digit and words.. It doesn't follow my specified quantifier `{1,3}` and `{1,10}`

Comment: This [demo](https://regex101.com/r/dM7gJ9/2) works fine for your regex too. Also be careful when you use `\w` it includes `_`(underscore) character too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your objective could be achieved by simple regex `\@\d{1,3}\w{1,10}`

But taking some precautions here. Using `[0-9]` instead of `\d` because `\d` could mean digits in many other scripts.

Also when you say `word` I guess you only want `[A-Za-z]` range.

So the final regex would be: `^\@[0-9]{1,3}[A-Za-z]{1,10}$`

### <kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dM7gJ9/3)**</kbd>

Comment: Please read http://php.net/manual/de/regexp.reference.meta.php - there's really no need to escape everything only to be on the safe side :-) In particular, `@` does not need to be escaped.